# Problema de Onclick

Tags: javascript, html

estoy realizando un programa que evalúa la edad de la persona, y, dependiendo de su edad, salen diferentes resultados.
Tengo un problema con `onclick` en el `input`, si llamo a mi función o método en la consola, me funciona y cumple con todo lo anterior. No entiendo porque falla.
Aquí el código:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
    <!-- Crear un programa en el que el usuario ingresapor 
    prompt su edad y en la cual se compruebe si la persona es menor 
    de 18 años informe por mensaje que no puede ingresar y 
    en la que el usuario es mayor
    o igual a 18 años de edad informe que si puede ingresar-->
    <script> 
    let edad = () =>{
        let num1 = parseInt(document.form1.edad.value);
        if(num1>=18){
            document.write("A ingresado exitosamente");
            alert("Ingresa aceptado");
        }else if(num1 < 18){
            if(num1==0||num1<0){
                alert("Error");
            }else if(num1>60){
                alert("Ingreso exitoso");
                document.write("Felicidades ingreso exitoso");
            }else{
                alert("Acceso denegado");
                document.write("Ingreso no permitido");
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <head>
        <h1>Ingresa tú edad para inicias</h1>
    </head>
    <main>
        <form name="form1">
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
            <label>Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
            <label>Edad:</label>
            <input type="number" name="edad" value="edad">
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="edad()">
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el nombre de la variable o de la funcion, cuando haces un click de un boton en el formulario, este esta en el contexto del form, y dentro del el ya hay un objeto llamado edad. que es el name de tu input. De hecho si hicieras un:

```
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="console.log(edad)">
```

Te imprimiria el input. Simplemente cambia el nombre de la funcion

```
<script> 
    let validarEdad = () =>{
        let num1 = parseInt(document.form1.edad.value);
        if(num1>=18){
            document.write("A ingresado exitosamente");
            alert("Ingresa aceptado");
        }else if(num1 < 18){
            if(num1==0||num1<0){
                alert("Error");
            }else if(num1>60){
                alert("Ingreso exitoso");
                document.write("Felicidades ingreso exitoso");
            }else{
                alert("Acceso denegado");
                document.write("Ingreso no permitido");
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

y ya en tu onclick lo llamas

```
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="validarEdad()">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias cambiando en nombre de la variable llego a funcionar, gracias, a uno no llegue a ver POO en js a un pero muchas gracias, si ya me había pasado en otros ejercicios antes pero no lo recordaba hasta ahora. Igual gracias. Y lo mismo para las otras respuestas que dan consejos sobre buenas practicas

Answer (score 0):

Poner eventos como atributo en los elementos, es una mala practica.

Te dejo como podrías hacerlo :

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn"); // accedemos al botón con su id

var boleano = true;

button.onclick = function() { // le agregamos el evento onclick
  // con this accedemos al elemento botón
  if (boleano) { // si es true el color cambiará a rojo
    this.style.color = "red";
    boleano = false;
  } else { // si es false el color cambiará a negro
    this.style.color = "black";
    boleano = true;
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Evento Click</button>
```

Espero haberte ayudado! :)

Comment: Esta genial también de esta forma osea que me dices que no use el onclick o onchange si que que lo añada como un evento. No sabia que se podía usar de esa manera hay alguna fuente o documentación que habla mas de ello. Desde ya gracias

Comment: @SolomanContreras aquí te dejo la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Answer (score 0):

Copié y pegué tu código en un archivo HTML y lo corrí usando [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) y me salió este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: edad is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Así que estuve investigando y leí esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

Así que cambié solo la línea

```
let edad = () =>{
```

a

```
function Edad(){
```

cambiando también como lo llamo en `onClick`

Al final, queda algo así:

```
<html lan="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
    <!-- Crear un programa en el que el usuario ingresapor 
    prompt su edad y en la cual se compruebe si la persona es menor 
    de 18 años informe por mensaje que no puede ingresar y 
    en la que el usuario es mayor
    o igual a 18 años de edad informe que si puede ingresar-->
</head>

<body>

    <head>
        <h1>Ingresa tú edad para inicias</h1>
    </head>
    <main>
        <form name="form1">
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
            <label>Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
            <label>Edad:</label>
            <input type="number" name="edad" value="edad">
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="Edad()">
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
<script>
    function Edad(){
        let num1 = parseInt(document.form1.edad.value);
        if (num1 >= 18) {
            document.write("A ingresado exitosamente");
            alert("Ingresa aceptado");
        } else if (num1 < 18) {
            if (num1 == 0 || num1 < 0) {
                alert("Error");
            } else if (num1 > 60) {
                alert("Ingreso exitoso");
                document.write("Felicidades ingreso exitoso");
            } else {
                alert("Acceso denegado");
                document.write("Ingreso no permitido");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Como buena práctica, te recomiendo poner tu tag `<script>` al final de tu documento.

Comment: Dale gracias por tu consejo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo y tiempo, lo voy a tener en cuenta cuando haga nuevos practicas. Desde ya gracias